# Error al utilizar hooks en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy utilizando useState y useEffect, pero a la hora de ver en la web la pagina, me tira este error. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Importaste React? `import React from 'react'`

Comment: Buenas, importe react y aun asi me muestra lo mismo

Comment: ¿Puedes adjuntar el código completo de tu componente ListadoPelículas? Por favor, adjúntalo con texto no con imágenes.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

En la captura de pantalla veo dos cosas principalmente:

1- falta import React,{useState,useEffect} from “react”

2- parece que estás utilizando una función en el useEffect antes de haberla declarado, si estás utilizando una expresión especialmente